# How to change photo format from circle to rectangle in a cv template

Tags: tikz-pgf, templates, cv

I just started using `LaTeX` again after a long hiatus to prepare a new CV. I'm using [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-source-cv/wrdjtkkytqcw). So I looked at the class definition .cls and found the custom photo command and the newcommand `\idphoto` and where everything is used, but I'm totally lost how to change the code so the picture is rectangular. Otherwise I really like the template, so it would be really nice if somebody knows how to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In the `cls` file, you have the definition of the `idphoto` command between lines 261 - 263, there you can show that is using the option circle.

```
\newcommand\idphoto{
  \tikz\path[fill overzoom image={\@photo}]circle[radius=0.5\linewidth];
}
```

if you change the circle part with something like `(0, 0) rectangle (2.5, 2.5)` you will have the photo into a rectangular shape.